# How do I use Split in the Mac OS X Terminal to split files directly to another directory?

Tags: macos, terminal

How do I use the OS X Terminal command `split` to split a file into several pieces, and store them in a different folder, on a different drive?

The reason is that I need to move files to a FAT32 store, but they are too large for the FAT32 4 GB file size constraint.

Also, I don't have enough space left on my HFS+ drive to split it there, and then move it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If Mac OS X's `split` acts just like the GNU Coreutils `split`, `cd` to the directory you wish the split files to reside in and then run the following command:

```
split -b <size> /location/of/big/file
```

Comment: BIG THANKS! :D Seems to work, as I'm currently "split-copying" now. Here's what I did: CD'd to the directory I wanted the files in, just as you told, and then I typed: `split -b 2048m /location/of/big/file` But I chose some other directories, though *LOL*

Comment: The obvious next question would be how to join the files back together again. The `join` command isn’t suitable. The `cat` command can be used instead: cat file1 file2 file 3 > onebigfile or cat file* > onebigfile