# Split and encrypt a folder before uploading online for backup

Tags: unix, terminal, encryption, online-backup, online-storage

I'd like to try out BackBlaze B2 to back up 400 GB of files. However, I'd like to zip and encrypt before uploading.

**Requirements**

- split a folder to multiple folders (folders contain videos and images)
- split should be based on size (or number of files if it's easier)
- folder naming should have a number at the end `~/Desktop/name0001/` for example
- zip each folder with the same password
- if a zipped folder were to be deleted, the rest can still be unzipped
- unzip and merge files back to the way they were before they were split and zipped
- runs on OSX terminal (but a linux answer would help out others too)

**Example input**

```
/path/to/folder/
  -someImage0001.png
  -someImage0002.png
  -...
  -someImage9999.png
```

**Output after splitting process**

```
someName01.zip //encrypted
someName02.zip //encrypted
...
```

**Output after unzipping and merging**

```
/path/to/folder/
  -someImage0001.png
  -someImage0002.png
  -...
  -someImage9999.png
```

I'm aware of [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190088/is-there-a-terminal-command-to-split-a-folder-in-two) two [posts](https://superuser.com/questions/313014/how-do-i-use-split-in-the-mac-os-x-terminal-to-split-files-directly-to-another-d/313016), but they fall short of my needs. I also know about about `zip -s <size>` option, but I'm worried that if one zip file gets corrupted, I won't be able to merge the rest back together.

Comment: This falls under software recommendations, which is offtopic here on SuperUser. Any archiver can split a large file into smaller portions, but indeed if one of the files get corrupted you won't be able to unzip.

Comment: I'm not looking for software recommendation, but a set of terminal commands instead. Where would be a more appropriate place for my question other than software recommendations?

Comment: What you want is not possible with zip, which is why it becomes a software recommendation. There's a software recommendations stack exchange site.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Perhaps I should ask three questions instead of one. 1. How to split contents of a folder by size and put it back together. 2. Rename each split folder. 3. Zip and encrypt a folder.

Comment: Well, if you edit out the part about zip -s <size> and that it gets corrupted, it becomes valid for SuperUser.

Comment: Just use EncFS, it's reverse encryption is perfect for online backups, and it uses "real" encryption (maybe not the best in existence, but worlds better than zip afaik)